# DAMLe Error: Error(mismatching type: Contract and value: ValueUnit)

Tags: python, daml

```
I am trying to exercise a multi-party contract through Python ledger API. The DAML contract code as below,

**DAML Contract code which causes this issue:**
-- verification multi-party agreement block
controller Agent1 can
  ApproveScore : ContractId PendingContract 
    do create this with Agent1 = Agent2
```

The Ledger API code which exercises the contract as below,

**Python Ledger API Code which executes this contract:**

```
approve_exercise_command = ExerciseCommand(
   template_id = Identifier(
      package_id = self.package_id,name = PENDING_CONTRACT
    ),
    contract_id = event.created.contract_id,
    choice = APPROVE_CHOICE,
    choice_argument = Value(unit = Empty())
  )
  approve_score_command = Command(exercise = approve_exercise_command)

**Error details:**

    status = StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT
        details = "DAMLe Error: Error(mismatching type: ApproveScore and value: ValueUnit)"
        debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1553510346.703290741","description":"Error received from peer","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1039,"grpc_message":"DAMLe Error: Error(mismatching type: ApproveScore and value: ValueUnit)","grpc_status":3}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, we figured out the issue with the help of a DA team. The issue is I am passing the empty parameter using Empty. With the latest SDK version of DA, we will have to pass the empty parameters alike below.

In the old SDK version to pass the empty parameters in the choice,

```
choice_argument = Value(unit = Empty())
```

In the new SDK version use like below,

```
 choice_argument = Value(
        record = Record(
         record_id = Identifier(
         package_id = self.package_id,
         name= "Main.ApproveScore"
        ),
       fields = [])
    )
```

Thanks, Stephen Compall for jumping in.

Answer (score 0):

"No input" for a choice in DAML is represented as a record type with no fields; that record type is named `ApproveScore` in your example.

I don't know the Python API in detail, but for what it should look like, I would say, imagine that your choice *did* have some input, what would the scaffolding around those arguments look like? Then just remove the arguments, leaving the scaffolding (i.e. the empty record construction) in place.

Comment: Yes, this choice doesn't require any input. I am passing the empty choice arguments into the ledger API. Even though I am getting the above error. Please find the updated summary above.

Comment: Looking at your summary, it has exactly the problem I describe: the representation of "empty choice arguments" is not unit anymore, though it used to be in the past. It is an ApproveScore record with no fields; the record type is named after the choice in each case.